# Codeigniter Unable to load the requested file:

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I have test my first code but had this error message:

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to load the requested file: first.php

```
<?php
class Ow extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($a){
        $this->load->view('first');
    }
}
?>
```

[image: file structure]

Comment: You need to create `first.php` file under folder `application/views`.

Comment: please check the view file extension . it must be in view folder with a name first.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `views` folder (application/views). add `first.php` file since it doesn't exists as said in your error message

Example Folder structure:

appname

- application

  - config
  - controllers

    - Ow.php
  - views

    - first.php
- system

Comment: the path of it is not application\views  ? i had copy files in this folder

Comment: I added an example to show where you put your first.php. if still doesnt work. then you need to show your folder structure.

Comment: i dont see any first.php on your views folder

Comment: yeah.  i was rename the files and forget it :D

Comment: btw dont remove your question. others might experience this also.

Comment: Unable to load the requested file:.php
What to do if the filename is missing completely?

Answer (score 0):

use this .htaccess file in your root directory

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```